# Sufficient conditions for directional derivatives of a particular function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the next:

Let $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function, periodic of period $2\pi$ and define the function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by $$f(r\cos(\theta), r\sin(\theta)) = rh(\theta).$$

Then all directional derivatives of $f$ exist at $(0,0)$ if and only if $h(\theta) = -h(\theta + \pi)$ for all $\theta.$

I was trying to use the definition of directional derivative; particularly there are partial derivatives and use this to get an expresion to get the desired equality but I cannot get something useful.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try and differentiate $f$ at $(0,0)$ in the direction $(\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta))$. We want to take the limit $\epsilon\to0$ of

$$\frac1\epsilon(f(\epsilon\cos(\theta), \epsilon\sin(\theta)) - f(0)) $$

If we are taking the limit from above (i.e. $\epsilon>0$ as it goes to zero), then we find the answer is $h(\theta)$. If we are taking the limit from below (i.e. $\epsilon<0$ as it goes to zero), then we find the answer is $-h(\theta+\pi)$. For the limit to be well-defined, and hence for the directional derivative to exist, it is necessary (and sufficient) that these functions agree.

Comment: Thanks @Alec B-G.